# Export Oracle Database User data from client

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am working on client system. There is a database on server contains many users. I have the access to database with a userid and password. my userid is "ncon" and Database name is 'HYDPPD'.

We are maintaining a Web-application with this database. Now we want to migrate database to another server.

my system is having toad version 9.5.0.31.
and oracle client version installed.

I want to export complete "ncon" user data from database on client system. user data contains 470 tables, 450 procedures, 20 views, 15 triggers and some functions.

I tried:

```
D:\>exp ncon/nconac_2014 file=ncon.dmp owner=necon

Export: Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production on Sat Mar 15 19:56:15 201

(c) Copyright 2000 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.


EXP-00056: ORACLE error 12560 encountered
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully

D:\>
```

Please any one help me out.
I have very less time to export data from database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an `exp` issue. TNS errors are related to net configuration. are you able to connect to the database ? try the same command but with  `exp ncon/nconac_2014@HYDPPD` (or what ever the entry name is for this databse - what you write after `@` when you connect to sqlplus or toad)

Comment: This is a sqlnet problem. Post your tnsnames.ora listener and sqlnet.ora files

Comment: Probably a good idea to edit out the password from your question